# Merging putIfAbsent followed by compute to one line

Tags: java, java-8

I have a feeling that the following code can be made little more concise:

```
changeMap.putIfAbsent(before, new Tuple(-1, -1));
changeMap.putIfAbsent(after, new Tuple(-1, -1));
changeMap.compute(before, (integer, tuple) -> new Tuple(index, tuple.right));
changeMap.compute(after, (integer, tuple) -> new Tuple(tuple.left, index));
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the merge function on Map